# C# implementation Button Animation shows weird behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button

I made a button animation by a c#(code) approach with a MouseEnter event to make the button bigger and with a MouseLeave event to make the button smaller again. It works if I hover on a button and wait till its done resizing and then hover off the button. But if I quickly hover over the same button twice or over a different button it shows weird behaviour. It think it is a multithreading issue and that the MouseEnter and MouseLeave methods are executed multiple times at the same time but I don't know how to solve it.

```
<Button Name="Redo" Click="ButtonPressed" Canvas.Left="148" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseEnter="MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MouseLeave">Redo</Button>
```

```c#
DispatcherTimer timer;
int elapsedTime = 0;
int interval = 1;
int totalTime = 5;
string name = null;

public void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.OriginalSource is not Button)
    {
        return;
    }
    //if (name != null)
    //    return;

    Button hoveredButton = e.OriginalSource as Button;
    name = hoveredButton.Name;
    elapsedTime = 0;
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();


    timer.IsEnabled = true;
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval);

    timer.Tick += delegate { MouseAnimation(1, hoveredButton); };
}
public void MouseAnimation(int resize, Button button)
{
    timer.Stop();
    if (elapsedTime > totalTime)
    {
        elapsedTime = 0;
        return;
    }


    timer.IsEnabled = true;
    button.Height = button.ActualHeight + resize;
    button.Width = button.ActualWidth + resize;


    elapsedTime += interval;
}
public void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //if (elapsedTime > 0)
    //    return;

    if (e.OriginalSource is not Button)
    {
        return;
    }

    Button hoveredButton = e.OriginalSource as Button;
    //if (hoveredButton.Name != name)
    //    return;
    //if (name == null)
    //    return;

    Button tempButton = (Button)e.OriginalSource;

    //if(e.OriginalSource != hoveredButton)
    //{   
    //    return;
    //}

    elapsedTime = 0;
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.IsEnabled = true;
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval);
    timer.Tick += delegate { MouseAnimation(-1, hoveredButton); };
    timer.IsEnabled = true;
    name = null;

}
```

I tried to store the name of a button in variable and look if the same button is hovered over twice but that didn't work.

Comment: Animations are done using XAML or the equivalent classes - XAML tags correspond to classes and their properties. It's never done by modifying UI element properties directly, because every modification forces a jerky redraw

Comment: The [WPF Animation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) show how to create animation objects in code. For every XAML tag the equivalent C# code is shown, eg `new DoubleAnimation();` to create a new animation object